# Which in-memory Java database is closest to MySQL & SqlServer for the purpose of unit testing?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, sql-server, unit-testing

I am looking for an in-memory database to use in unit-testing my data access layer. In production, most   of my classes will be running against MySQL 5.1 but some will have read access to Microsoft SQL Server.

In the past, [I've had issues with  differences dialects between different databases tripping up unit testing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7432350/254477) (resulting once in using AspectJ to mangle the queries before execution!!!) so I'd like to avoid that as much as possible.

So, I was wondering **which Java *in-memory* database is closest in behaviour to MySql & SQL Server?** My main concern is mostly with regards to MySQL since we use it the most and -AFAIK- it has the most non-standard syntax. This is for unit testing so scalability, performance, efficiency, etc are not important.

Comment: A unit (or integration) test against a database which is not the one used in production is worthless.

Comment: "[Don't let the perfect be the enemy of the good](http://www.goodreads.com/quotes/215866-le-mieux-est-l-ennemi-du-bien-the-perfect-is-the)" - Voltaire. It's not ideal but it will still pick-up errors like putting your WHERE close before your FROM which happens when generating SQL etc.

Comment: @ArtB, agree with the quote, but your question is about the specific differences between mysql and an in memory database that you have _had issues with differences dialects between different databases tripping up unit testing_.  This sounds like you need to ensure it works with mysql, and as such, no other database will do...

Comment: Well I just want to get rid of the hacks, or minimise the number of them required. I'm fine with them if they're necessary.

Answer (score 1):

I actually use a MySQL database in my unit tests to ensure correctness.  When using JUnit, you can do something like this:

```
@Before
public void initialize() {
    try {
        dataSource.getConnection().close();
        logger.info( "got a connection, so we can assume the configuration is correct..." );
    }
    catch ( Exception e ) {
        logger.warn( "skipping tests as no connection is available.  check spring config: {}", e.getMessage() );
        e.printStackTrace();
        assumeNoException( e );
    }
}
```

This runs before every test and if it cannot connect to the database, it will skip the test without causing a failure via `assumeNoException`.  This way, if you need to build on a system that is not configured for MySQL you can, but if your developers configure their system correctly, it will use an installed instance of MySQL.  I know this is not a direct answer to your question, but thought it may be useful anyway...

Comment: But then your unit test is not self-contained. Also, that means that likely you will just not get your tests run because they didn't deploy an appropriately configured server and your tests will rot.

Comment: @ArtB, while it is true that this unit test is not totally self contained, it is safe to run without configuration (safe as in it will build, not as in the code passes tests).  Your second comment makes it sound like you are doing some sort of continuous integration scenario...  If that is the case, you just have to ensure your build server is configured, this should not be too much to ask for...

Comment: We have offshore workers, we develop on Windows, build on OS X, and deploy on Linux. We have separate maintenance teams. Any excuse not to run the tests or having them fail silently will lead to the being useless. Setting up an external DB now requires a PO for the server and the sysadmins will have to maintain it and... if it's not internal it's not gonna happen.